# Sort an array of objects based on key/value of array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I need to sort an array of objects. How can I sort this array based on key `arrval[index]`?

```
arr = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Name 1', arrval: [5, 3, 1] },
  { id: 1, name: 'Name 2', arrval: [6, 4, 3] },
  { id: 2, name: 'Name 3', arrval: [3, 2, 0] },
]
```

So if I want to sort it by arrval[1], ascending, the result should be:

```
arr = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Name 3', arrval: [3, 2, 0] },
  { id: 0, name: 'Name 1', arrval: [5, 3, 1] },
  { id: 1, name: 'Name 2', arrval: [6, 4, 3] },
]
```

I can already sort this if I sort it by `id` or `name` but I can't seem to make it work by `arrval`

Comment: If you know how to sort by `id` or `name`, what prevents you doing the same for *the first index* of `arrval`?

Comment: It is exactly same as you sort with `id` and `name` . `arr.sort((a, b) => a.arrval[0] - b.arrval[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as that

```js
const src = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Name 1', arrval: [5, 3, 1] },
  { id: 1, name: 'Name 2', arrval: [6, 4, 3] },
  { id: 2, name: 'Name 3', arrval: [3, 2, 0] },
]

const sortByKeyIdx = ([...arr], key, idx) =>
  arr
    .sort(({[key]:a}, {[key]:b}) => 
      a[idx]-b[idx])
    
console.log(sortByKeyIdx(src, 'arrval', 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `arrval` index and sort it like you normally would. You can try this solution:

```js
const sort = index => {
  const arr = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Name 1', arrval: [5, 3, 1] },
    { id: 1, name: 'Name 2', arrval: [6, 4, 3] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Name 3', arrval: [3, 2, 0] }
  ]

  return arr.sort((x, y) => x.arrval[index] - y.arrval[index])
}

console.log(sort(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort by `arrval` like you sort by `id` or `name`

```js
arr.sort( (a, b) => a.arrval[0] - b.arrval[0] )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to do this

**first**:

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Name 1',
    arrval: [5, 3, 1]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name 2',
    arrval: [6, 4, 3]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name 3',
    arrval: [3, 2, 0]
  },
]
let index = 1
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.arrval[index] < b.arrval[index]) return -1
  else if (a.arrval[index] < b.arrval[index]) return 1
  else return 0
})

console.log(arr)
```

**second**:

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Name 1',
    arrval: [5, 3, 1]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name 2',
    arrval: [6, 4, 3]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name 3',
    arrval: [3, 2, 0]
  },
]
let index = 1
arr.sort((a, b) => a.arrval[1] - b.arrval[1])

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer sorts by the first array value. If you need to be able to deal with ties, where then the second array value becomes decisive, ...etc, then use this:

```js
    
const src = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Name 1', arrval: [5, 3, 3] },
  { id: 1, name: 'Name 2', arrval: [5, 3, 1] },
  { id: 2, name: 'Name 3', arrval: [5, 2, 0, 1] },
  { id: 3, name: 'Name 4', arrval: [5, 2, 0] },
]

src.sort(({arrval: a}, {arrval: b}) => {
    for (let i = 0, len = Math.min(a.length, b.length); i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return a[i] - b[i];
    }
    return a.length - b.length;
});

console.log(src);
```